# Generic method in a non-generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm sure I've done this before, but can't find any example of it! Grrr...

For example, I want to convert an `IList<T>` into a `BindingList<T>`:

```
public class ListHelper
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList(IList<T> data)
    {
        BindingList<T> output = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (T item in data)
            output.Add(item);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question here? Yes, generic methods are fine in non-generic classes (System.Linq.Enumerable being probably the biggest example).

Comment: @Jon - he missed the <T> in ToBindingList

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
ToBindingList <T> (...)
```

---

```
public class ListHelper
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        BindingList<T> output = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            output.Add(item);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Wouldn't this be simpler?

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        return new BindingList<T>(list);
    }
}
```

It's so simple that we don't need an extension method ...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you allowed to do that? Is there a constructor in BindingList that takes an array as argument and makes a BindingList out of it?

Comment: @Imray it's not an array, it's an `IList`, and there is a constructor that accepts it as an argument: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/BindingList.cs,4f2405ea796059fa,references line 65

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by extension method and it would be better.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(this IList<T> list) 
    {
        BindingList<T> bindingList = new BindingList<T>();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            bindingList.Add(item);
        }

        return bindingList;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way I'd do it... maybe even from IEnumerable<T> (sinc all you do is foreach)

Comment: Yes, IEnumerable would be better.